# I am trying to inflate a menu from my HomeActivity but the app crashes when i click any of the items on the list

Tags: java, android

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 22175
        android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x3c
            at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:367)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6370)
            at com.example.myapplication.HomeActivity.updateData(HomeActivity.java:244)
            at com.example.myapplication.HomeActivity$4$1.onClick(HomeActivity.java:187)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
            at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
            at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)



public  void updateData(){

        AlertDialog.Builder mydialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(HomeActivity.this);
        View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_inputfield,null);
        final AlertDialog dialog = mydialog.create();

        dialog.setView(mView);


        final EditText edt_Type = mView.findViewById(R.id.edt_type_upd);
        final EditText edt_Amount = mView.findViewById(R.id.edt_amount_upd);
        final EditText edt_Note = mView.findViewById(R.id.edt_note_upd);

        edt_Type.setText(type);
        edt_Type.setSelection(type.length());

        edt_Amount.setText(amount);
        edt_Amount.setSelection(String.valueOf(amount).length());
        //edt_Amount.setSelection(Integer.toString(amount).length());

        edt_Note.setText(note);
        edt_Note.setSelection(note.length());

        Button btnUpdate = mView.findViewById(R.id.btn_save_upd);
        Button btnDelete = mView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete_upd);

        btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                type = edt_Type.getText().toString().trim();

                String mAmount = String.valueOf(amount);
                mAmount = edt_Amount.getText().toString().trim();

                note = edt_Note.getText().toString().trim();

                int amt = Integer.parseInt(mAmount);

                String date = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());

                Data data = new Data(type,amt,note,date,post_key);

                mDatabase.child(post_key).setValue(data);

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

And I am calling this updateData() method from 

   

  protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
    
            FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Data,MyViewHolder>adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Data, MyViewHolder>
                    (
                            Data.class,
                            R.layout.item_data,
                            MyViewHolder.class,
                            mDatabase
                    )
            {
    
      
    
          @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(MyViewHolder viewHolder, final Data model, final int position) {
    
                viewHolder.setDate(model.getDate());
                viewHolder.setType(model.getType());
                viewHolder.setAmount(model.getAmount());
                viewHolder.setNote(model.getNote());
    
                viewHolder.myview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
    
                        post_key=getRef(position).getKey();
                        type=model.getType();
                        note=model.getNote();
                        amount=model.getAmount();
    
                        //amount=model.getAmount();
    
                        updateData();
                    }
                });
    
            }
        };
    
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

I am making a daily shopping list app and I have used firebaserecycler adapter to create a list but when I click on any of the list items it does not show the inflated menu as it should.
Any help would be appreciated!
When I click on any of the items the app keeps crashing.
It's giving me an inflated menu when I click on the floating action button
and when I click on any of the list items it does not work

Comment: Post your code? It seems though that you are trying to put a string but maybe instead sending an int? Such as, int a = 5; editText.setText(a); something of the sort. Anyway, code is needed to see what's wrong

Comment: Ok I will edit the post and paste my update code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

line

```
edt_Amount.setText(amount);
```

amount is integer. When you call setText with an int it's looking for the ID of amount and that's why it's failing. Change that line to:

```
edt_Amount.setText(String.valueOf(amount));
```

I'll keep reading your code to see if it happens more, will edit if so

Edit:

```
String mAmount = String.valueOf(amount);
            mAmount = edt_Amount.getText().toString().trim();

            note = edt_Note.getText().toString().trim();

            int amt = Integer.parseInt(mAmount);
```

This part is kind of bad practice, you are taking an int, converting it to String and doing nothing with it. Reassign that string to a different value. Then parses that value back to an int, you can replace it with:

```
int amt = Integer.parseInt(edt_Amount.getText().toString().trim());
```

Note that the line

> ```
>             note = edt_Note.getText().toString().trim();
> ```

is okay, you can keep it after / before the other lines

Comment: Changed the value to this => edt_Amount.setText(String.valueOf(amount).length()); and reassigned the value   int amt = Integer.parseInt(edt_Amount.getText().toString().trim()); But still it is showing the same error

Comment: Sorry, I changed my line, you don't need the .length in the end.

Comment: The error is in line 367, according to the original error message, mind adding the numbers of the lines or just mark lines 362-372?